# SQL Insert states that rows were inserted but yet none show up when running select all from that table

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, common-table-expression

I am trying to get better at using CTE in Oracle SQL Developer have ran the below code which I have simplified to it's basic structure. It ran successfully and said the [x] number of rows were inserted, but yet when I run SELECT * FROM [TableName], nothing appears even after committing. Anyone see where I messed up?

Please note that I took out the actual names and such and substituted them with < some field > that represents what it is.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE <TableName> ;
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_date_format = 'MM/DD/YYYY' ;
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE <TableName> (
< Table Field Names> <Table Field Data Types>
);
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
GRANT SELECT ON <TableName>  TO <User1>;
GRANT SELECT ON <TableName>  TO <User2>;
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO <TableName>
SELECT
  <Fields From CTE1, CTE2 & CTE3>
FROM (

WITH <CTE1> AS
  (
SELECT DISTINCT 
<Field Names From Table1>
FROM <Table1>
WHERE <Specific Field> NOT IN ('<input>')
  ),
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  <CTE2> AS
  (
SELECT DISTINCT 
<Fields From Table2>
FROM <Table2>
WHERE <Specific Field>  >= '<input>' 
AND <Specific Field> IN ('<input>')
GROUP BY 
  <Fields From Table2>
),
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<CTE3> AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT 
<Fields From Table3>
FROM <Table3>
WHERE  <Specific Field> = '<input>'
AND <Specific Field> >= '<input>'
AND <Specific Field> IN ('<input>')
)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT DISTINCT
*
FROM <CTE1> a

LEFT JOIN <CTE2> b
ON a.ID = b.ID

LEFT JOIN <CTE3> c
ON to_char(a.ID) = c.ID
)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
COMMIT;
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT count(*) FROM <TableName>;
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: With such a general description, it is difficult to guess what might be wrong. I'd rather if you posted sample queries we could reproduce. Anyway: it is unclear which user owns the table being inserted, and which user ran the INSERT. Because, you granted privileges to some other users. Is there any synonym involved? Other owners? As far as I can tell, if Oracle says "x rows inserted", then you should see them. They don't just "disappear".

Comment: Yeah, It's a work related query, so I don't want to disclose all the tables and fields associated with it. The grand access is just for my peers so they can read it. I am really the only one that uses it or ever updates it. I ran the insert and those grants are to other usernames aside from mine.

Comment: It must have something to do with the CTE format...I just ran the exact code but without the CTE format and instead in a standard JOIN format and it works correctly. Not sure why that occurred.

Comment: Not exposing your actual work is understandable. But we cannot do anything with a completely 'query'. Take your actual query, generalize table and column for example table1 col11, col12, table2 col21, col22 ... Now take the ddl for those tables do the same renaming, also remove any unnecessary columns. Then post the result along with sample data and expected results - all as text - NO IMAGES.